# Can't install laracasts/utilities through composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

If I have the package list like that:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "illuminate/support": "~5.0",
    "way/generators": "2.*",
    "intervention/image": "~2.1",
    "doctrine/inflector": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
    "laracasts/utilities": "~2.0"
  },
```

or `"illuminate/support": "~4.0"`, then I get error:

```
    - way/generators 2.6.1 requires illuminate/support ~4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - way/generators 2.6 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> no matching package found.
    - way/generators 2.5 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> no matching package found.
    ... and so on
```

So, if I change package to `"illuminate/support": ">4"`, I get this:

```
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.18
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v4.2.17
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
...
- laracasts/utilities 2.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.0
...
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
...
```

Can you tell me how to compose the package list so that I can run the composer update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is probably install:

```
"laracasts/utilities": "1.0.*"
```

and not

```
"laracasts/utilities": "~2.0"
```

Also you should not put `illuminate/support` into your `composer.json` if you put it here only to use for `laracasts/utilities` because it will conflict with `way/generators` and `laracasts/utilities` (1.0.*)

Comment: That worked. But why should I install an older version of `/utilities`?

Comment: Because new one requires you to install in fact Laravel 5